# The visibility of the items change when scrolled ListView

Tags: android

I am using a list view and an adapter for loading a list,each list item has a TextView,EditText and Image..I set the visibility of the arrow and the Edit text according to the position of the list row,everything works fine when I load the list for the first time...
But when I scroll through the list,visibility of the items keep changing...Kindly help me in this issue...The relevant codes has been attached...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"  android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/textview_add_lot_list" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:paddingTop="10dip" android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"/>
    <EditText android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/et_add_lot_list"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageview_arrow_add_lot_list" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible" android:src="@drawable/more_reviews_arrow"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java code activity...

```
final ArrayList<String> listItems       =   new ArrayList<String>();
        listItems.add("Parking name");
        listItems.add("Address");
        listItems.add("City");
        listItems.add("State");
        listItems.add("Zip");
        listItems.add("Phone");
        listItems.add("Web Address");
        listItems.add(" ");
        listItems.add("Parking Image");
        listItems.add(" ");
        listItems.add("Open Hours");
        listItems.add(" ");
        listItems.add("Web Reviews");

        final AddParkingLotAdapter adapter  =   new AddParkingLotAdapter(mAppContext,0,listItems);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Java code...adapter

```
public class AddParkingLotAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private ArrayList<String> mStrings;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private AppContext mContext;

    private static int NON_EMPTY_ROW    =   1;                                                                                                          
    private static int EMPTY_ROW       =    0;

    public AddParkingLotAdapter(Context context, int resId, List<String> strings) {
        super(context, resId,strings);
        mStrings        =   (ArrayList<String>) strings;
        mContext        =   (AppContext) context;
        mInflater       =   LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;                               
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mStrings.size();     
    }
    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mStrings.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position==7||position==9||position==11){
            return EMPTY_ROW;
        }else{
            return NON_EMPTY_ROW;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView itemTextView   =   null;

        //different inflations for different type rows..
        if(getItemViewType(position) == EMPTY_ROW){
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView         =   mInflater.inflate(R.layout.review_empty_row, null);
            }
        }else if(getItemViewType(position) == NON_EMPTY_ROW){
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView     =   mInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_parkinglist_item, null);
            }
            itemTextView        =   (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_add_lot_list);
            itemTextView.setText(mStrings.get(position));
            if (position==3||position==8||position==10||position==12){
                ImageView itemImageView       =   (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_arrow_add_lot_list);
                itemImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                EditText editText             =   (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_add_lot_list);
                editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this code:

```
if (position==3||position==8||position==10||position==12){
    ImageView itemImageView       =   (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_arrow_add_lot_list);
    itemImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    EditText editText             =   (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_add_lot_list);
    editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

you've got no **else** clause. That means that if position is 0,1,2,4,5 or 6 you don't explicitly set the visibility of the views and so the visibility will be whatever it was set to when the views were recycled. If `convertView` is non-null, you always need to reset the visibility of any items whose visibility may be been modified earlier.